# Lie point symmetries of $y''+y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, symmetry

I need help to find symmetries of 2nd order ODE $y''+y=0.$
Here is my work:

Criterion gives $\eta^{2} + \eta=0$ which I solved and got determining equations as

$1) Y': 2\eta_{xy} - \xi_{xx}+ 3y\xi_y=0$

$2) Y'^2: \eta_{yy}- 2\xi_{xy}=0$

$3) Y'^3: \xi_{yy}=0$

$4) Const: \eta_{xx}- y\eta_y+ 2y\xi_x+ \eta$

After solving this $(3)$ I got

$\xi=a(x)y+b(x)$

and solving $(2)$ yields

$\eta= a'(x)y^2+c(x)y+d(x)$

and $(1)$ gives

$a''+a=0 $ and $b''-2c'$

and $(4)$ gives

$a''+a'=0, c''+2b'=0, d''+d=0$

Where (,) denotes partial derivative w.r.t 'x'.

I solved it uptill here but here I got stuck the equations are just as same as the equation I started working with... Please if anybody can help me do it or can give a clue.. It will be highly acknowledged. (Apology for inconvenience while reading it.!)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a linear ODE so it's normal the ode to appear. But I think something is wrong because `a` shouldn't satisfy the ode.